# "member of type foo has private copy constructor" error: why's it an error?

Tags: c++, class, copy-constructor

I was trying to define a class like this:

```
#include <library/foo.h>

class my_class {
private:
  someone_elses foo;
public:
  myclass();
  ~myclass();
  //...
};
```

But the compiler failed: "field foo of type someone_elses has a private copy constructor". Now I know that I can address this by:

```
class my_class {
private:
  someone_elses *foo;
//...
};

my_class::my_class() { foo = new someone_elses(); }
my_class::~my_class() { delete foo; }
```

My question is why does the compiler care whether an object's field implements an accessible copy constructor?

Comment: What is the line of code which gave the error?

Comment: unsurprisingly it's the declaration of the field `foo` ;-)

Comment: Because your class `my_class` has an implicit compiler-generated copy constructor that just copies all the fields. If `someone_elses` has a private copy constructor, then the `foo` field cannot be copied. You should write your own copy constructor for `my_class` that implements proper copying.

Comment: I guess that somewhere you try to make a copy of such object. Like passing by-value to a function.

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/uB3bl.

Comment: @HristoIliev Your comment explains things better than both given answers. You should post this an an answer.

Comment: @interjay - but [not for me](http://ideone.com/rgTRv).

Comment: A better solution (than using RAW pointers) would be to disable the copy constructor of `my_class`. Your current solution is even more broken as you are going to get double deletes. See rule of three.

Comment: *Aside*: "I know that I can address this" -- not really. Don't forget the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: @Robᵩ I find it hard to forget a rule I've yet to come across, but thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first version, when you are copying instances of `my_class`, and you must be somewhere that you're not showing us, you are doing a deep copy of `someone_elses`.

In the latter version, when you do the same thing, you are making a shallow copy of a pointer to an instance of `someone_elses`.  Thus you don't make a copy but instead have a pointer to the same instance in both copies of `my_class`.

Since you are in fact deleting `someone_elses` in your destructor you are going to run into all kinds of problems.  You need to be able to copy `someone_elses` but it seems you're not allowed to for some reason that the author of that class thought was so important that they made it impossible.

How to respond to this problem depends too much on the details you left out.  It may be that you cannot allow copies of `my_class` and should be making its copy constructor private as well.  This will of course break something somewhere else because that constructor is not created if it's not used.

Comment: +1 For noticing, that OP must make some copy in undisclosed part of code. If no copy made, inability to generate copy constructor is not an issue.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware that I _am_ copying a `my_class` anywhere - but I'd accidentally written a Java-ish initialiser `my_class bar = my_class();` which was trying to use the copy constructor. *facepalm*

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that your `my_class` copy constructor invokes `someone_elses`' copy constructor. You would have to define a copy constructor that doesn't copy construct `someone_elses`, although semantically that doesn't make much sense.

```
class my_class {
private:
  someone_elses foo;
public:
  my_class(const my_class& rhs) {
   // do nothing, end up with default constructed someone_elses.
  } 
  myclass();
  ~myclass();
  //...
};
```

Answer (score 2):

**C++03 standard 12.8 (Copying class objects) Copy construction:**

> Each subobject is copied in the manner appropriate to its type:
>
> - **if the subobject is of class type, the copy constructor for the class is used;**
> - if the subobject is an array, each element is copied, in the manner appropriate to the element type;
> - if the subobject is of scalar type, the built-in assignment operator is used.

Your code breaks the first requirement, if the copy constructor of the sub-object `someone_elses` in your case is `private` it cannot be used and hence the compiler accurately points out the error.

Answer (score 1):

Because the copy constructor of `my_class` will invoke the copy constructor of `foo`. This is an object, not a pointer, so its copy constructor needs to be invoked.

Answer (score 1):

> why does the compiler care whether an object's field implements an accessible copy constructor?

Because your program invokes it, in `my_class`'s implicit copy constructor.  Consider:

```
int main () {
  my_class m1;
  my_class m2(m1);
}
```

The creation of `m2` invokes `my_class::my_class(const my_class&)`. If you didn't provide one, one is automatically provided for you. This *implicit* copy constructor merely copies each field of `m1` into the corresponding field of `m2`. Specifically, it must copy `foo`.

But, since `someone_elses::someone_else(const someone_else&)` is private, it cannot copy `foo`. Thus the error.